# WordPress Meta data write/save race conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am building A/B Testing into a WordPress PLugin.

A Landing Page custom post type record can have any number of A/B Test Variations for the page.  Each variation is assigned an alphabet letter A-Z.

All the variations for a page are stored together in a single Meta data key in the database using the built in WordPress Meta data functionality.

Below is an example of the Meta data for 1 page that has 4 Variations.

When the page is loaded for a user, they are served 1 of these 4 variations when viewing this particular page.  The `'ab-variation-views'` key for the variation they are viewing is updated by +1 on each page load.

I am a little concerned when thinking about it now though.  If 10 users load this page at once and the 10 randomly got served 1 of the 4 variations below.  When it updates the meta data increment the view counter for each of the 10 users.  I am thinking there might be a race condition/problem here.

If 4 of the 10 users are viewing Variation B and updating its views count +1, perhaps they wont all get saved or even a view count from another variation.

Should I consider storing my AB Test Variation data in its own database table?  If I did, each page variation could have its own record instead of all variations for a page sharing the same record and field!

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'B',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'bbbbbb',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'bbbbbbbbbbbb',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'C',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'ccccc',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'ccccccccccccccccc',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'D',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'dddddddd',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'd',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'E',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'eeeeeeee',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'eeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
)
```

Comment: `AB Test Variation data in its own database table` ... if your on high traffic yep do a transaction type table  its better than locking up rows between a read and write.. Or you can use mysql to increment the value if it has its own row in the post_meta table. that way no race condition (once it's only increment) and no large volume data to worry about when pulling data for reports.

Comment: @David I am thinking I might should switch to its own DB table for other reasons now.  If you look at my sample data above it has just 4 AB test variations for a page and the editor key in a real data set would likely be a large set of HTML for the page content on each of the 4.  Basically this 1 DB column would be huge!  With a separate DB table, each variation can have its own row and additionally on each row, each of the keys above would have there own column on the row instead of everything crammed into a single column and single record/row.  This is just how WP meta handles it now

Comment: @David unfortunately it's a pain at this stage to re-write the whole structure of my app but I think it is the right thing to do